# Disable the context menu in chrome apps?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, contextmenu, google-chrome-app

I am trying to write a chrome app which is set to fullscreen and started with Google's getting started tutorial from here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app

Now i am trying to disable the context menu which appears on right click.

Is that possible? And if so, how? I was searching over and over but couldn't find a solution. Please help!

Comment: The Point is i want to write a kiosk system with no keyboard and only a mouse as input which gets installed at an exhibition. So i don't think the viewers expect a context menu to appear.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Chrome context menu only apear on debugging app (loaded from a directory).**

But if you still want to disable context menu on your whole chrome app, simply use preventDefault() on the onContext event of your document... (every your custom context menu ll still work...)

For js [(demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/GFj48/):

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
});
```

For dart:

```
document.onContextMenu.listen((e)=>e.preventDefault());
```

Comment: thaaank you very much. packaging the app works! :) sorry for my low reputation - i wish to vote up your post.

Comment: @user2635541 What you can and should do is to accept the answer; it will also give you a small rep boost.